# Прошу помощи с AlertView и стилем UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Я использую конструкцию такую:

```
- (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alertNNumber = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Enter Number" message:@"Enter number from 1 till 100 000" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Enter" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertNNumber setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [alertNNumber show];
}
```

можно ли чтоб при выводе стиля UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput открывалась сразу цыфровая клавиатура? или как ограничить ввод любых других символов проме цыфр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто:

```
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
UITextField *alertTextFi = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
[alertTextFi setDelegate:self];
[alertTextFi setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[alert show];
```

Comment: для TextField пойдёт  [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
а вот в конструкции [alertNNumber setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad]; компилятор не знает что такое setKeyboardType. пишет no visible @interface for "UIAlertView" declares the selector 'setKeyboardType'

Comment: ААА :) Сорри... Мой косяк :)

Исправил ответ!!!

Comment: Теперь работает)) а что мы делаем? поверх алерта создаём текстовое поле? у меня [alertTextFi setDelegate:self]; на self ругаеться! я закоментировал вообще эту строку, вроде работает. Это страшно?
я конечно добавил @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate>, ну а если без добавления, то что будет?)))

Comment: Делегат не обязательно, можешь убирать. Просто я подумал, что ты хочешь обрабатывать ввод от 1 до 100 000, вот и добавил. По поводу TextField - мы не создаем, а Берем из алерта (из его стека) эту строчку и модифицируем. :)

Comment: dark_Haron, мозги уже кипят)) как обработать это текстовое поле, чтоб если не правельное значение, то вызывало или алерт, или просто правельный символ? я даже незнаю как правильно сделать if !и к чему его крепить?

Comment: - (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonAlertIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag ==1)
    {
    temp6LvlAlertTextStr = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];
    temp6LvlAlertTextInt = [temp6LvlAlertTextStr intValue];
        
        if (temp6LvlAlertTextInt <=0 && temp6LvlAlertTextInt>100000) {

            [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text = @"1";
            
        }
       Else
       { 
          //выполняем когда всё правильно       
        }   
                не работает ничего!!! если вводишь 0!! вообще креш проги происходит.

Comment: 1. Такие вопросы надо выводить в отдельный вопрос. ----- 2. Дык, у тебя логическая ошибка: ЗНАЧЕНИЕ меньше или равно 0 И больше 10000 :) Не видишь противоречия? Делай отдельный пост, будем решать эту задачку :)

Comment: Правильно:
if (temp6LvlAlertTextInt <=0 || temp6LvlAlertTextInt>100000)

Comment: как по мне, условие (меньше либо равняется нулю и больше ста тысяч) никогда не пройдет. Здесь нужно стрелки развернуть и выполнить " //выполняем когда всё правильно ", иначе  [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text = @"1";.

upd: ну и убрать "равно" из первого сравнения и добавить во второе